# parse R.java class

Tags: android, parsing

When I'm in an activity, how can I get die complete code of the R.java class to parse it?
I want to parse for a resource String.

In my R class there's the following entry:

```
public static int abs__home=0x7f04000a;
```

And I want to search the whole text of R.java for the String "abs__home". I really need to search for the string.

Comment: it is a pre/post compiler action or what? there is no R.java file in apk file

Comment: need the R.string.bla for testing tool. Uhm nice to receive all that -1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getIdentifier()

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("abs__home", "string", getPackageName());
```

if the `name` (`abs__home`) does not exits inside the resources,  you will get `0`